# Matplotlib. Plotting in 'for loops' to same axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a rather simple problem but something that's had me stumped for 2days.
I need to plot 2+ files. Each file will need to be plotted on a total of 25 plots but must be plotted on the same set of axes. (ie. if theres 2 files I need 25 plots with 2 lines on each plot).

I have this sudo code which generates 50 plots (One line for each)...which is wrong

```
with open(bamlist, 'r') as bamlist:
    for bam in bamlist:     #Opens the 2 files
        'Generate data Here'
        dataframe = []
        for line in data:
            line = line.split("\t")
            dataframe.append(line[0:4:1])
        df = pd.DataFrame(dataframe, columns=['Chromosome', 'Position', 'N', 'BaseCount'])

        grouped_df = df.groupby('Chromosome')     #groups dataframe into the required 25plots
        for df in grouped_df:
            density_data = 'Get density data from df'
            f, ax = plt.subplots()          
            sns.kdeplot(density_data, ax=ax, linewidth=1)
            pp.savefig()
pp.close()
```

Is there a way to revert back to the initial set of axis the 2nd time the for loop is entered so that I will get 2 lines per plot with 25plots (as opposed to 50)?

Comment: do you want 25 subplots on one figure, or 25 separate figures?

Comment: Either will do. separate figures will be easier to view tho.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem stems from your use of:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots()
```

This means that you generate a new subplot every time you hit that line (in your case, 50 times). You need to generate 25 subplots and reference them later on. You can do something like:

```
axes = []
for i in range(25):
    f,ax = plt.subplots()
    axes.append(ax)
```

Then in your loop:

```
for df_index in range(len(grouped_df)):
    df = grouped_df[df_index]
    density_data = 'Get density data from df'
    sns.kdeplot(density_data, ax=axes[df_index], linewidth=1)
```

You can also do a check to see if the axis doesn't exist (if it extends to more than 25 subplots or something), and if not, create it.

Comment: Thanks for that! helped a lot! Also got it to work with plot.figure()

Comment: Thankyou for your response. I'm happy that it helped, and I'm glad that you figured out to use the figure() instead of subplots() to produce the data in new plots (This hadn't been clarified in the comments before I wrote my response). If this answer is to your liking, and you feel that it can help other people who search for the same thing, please "accept" the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Using plt.figure() also gets the job done...

```
iterate = -1
for df in grouped_df:
    iterate += 1
    plt.figure(iterate)
    density_data = 'Get density data from df'
    sns.kdeplot(density_data, linewidth=1)
    pp.savefig()
pp.close()
```